# Converting the timestamp of type YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000-08:00 to YYYYMMDD

Tags: sql, date, datetime, oracle10g

I have column of datatype varchar2 for example it store the values in thi format (2002-01-11T00:00:00.000-08:00).
But I want to have the value in the format of this type YYYYMMDD.

I just wanted to have this queried in SQL(Using SQL developer) statement.

My NLS is having the date format of DD-MON-RR and time stamp format is DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM

Can someone help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use FROM_UNIXTIME

```js
SELECT
  FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp_field) AS formatted_date
FROM
  tablename;
```

Comment: Hi Shekhar,thanks for the response .But FROM_UNIXTIME function is supported in MYSQL ,not in SQL database.I want to Change the format in SQL database.

Comment: In sql You can't. a timestamp is neither a date nor a time. 

timestamp is a data type that exposes automatically generated binary numbers, which are guaranteed to be unique within a database.  So it has no time related value, to convert in datetime

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112) AS [YYYYMMDD]

Comment: Thanks Alfaiz,still not able to convert the format as I'm trying in SQL database.Any functions which helps in SQL database would be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char(
  to_date(
    substr('2002-01-11T00:00:00.000-08:00',1,10)
    ,'YYYY-MM-DD')
  ,'YYYYMMDD')
from dual;

20020111
```

Comment: Jeffrey,one more help needed on the same,the solution which you provided converts only one date in the date column of my table.I want to have all the date in the date column should apprear like YYYYMMDD.L_date is the date coulmn in prc_tab table.Could you help on this please?

Comment: Just substitute your column and table into the query.